# Are HTTP headers handled automatically by the browser in AJAX responses?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, http-headers, http-post

Here's my situation: I make an ajax post to a server endpoint, and it sends me back some JSON data in response. This JSON response also includes the `Set-cookie` header.

Does the cookie get set *automatically* when it's in a response to an ajax request, or do I have to read it out of the headers and do it manually?

(As opposed to the headers being present on the response to a form submit, where I know the browser will be handling the response and its headers on its own, no JS necessarily involved.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it gets set automatically. An AJAX request is *just* an HTTP request. You can send Cookie headers, and receive Set-Cookie Headers normally.